# How to iterate/navigate through each character in a character set (e.g., US-ASCII or IBM037, in proper sequence)?

Tags: java

I want to iterate through each character in a character set (primarily US-ASCII and IBM037) and then print all alphanumeric characters (or all printable characters) in the proper character set sequence. Is it possible without creating static arrays?

Comment: You could try encoding and decoding each character to see if its a member of the character set. This wouldn't take more than a faction of a second.

Comment: The [ICU project](http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion/data) may have the tools to make these sorts of questions easier.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, Right but I wouldn't get the proper character sequence that way.

Comment: *"in the proper character set sequence"* - How do you define the *proper sequence*? For example I would normally expect numbers to appear before letters, but you apparently expect the reverse...

Comment: @thkala,  In US_ASCII, numbers, uppercase letters, lowercase letters. In IBM037, lowercase letters, uppercase letters, then numbers.

Comment: @Gyles, once you have found a solution you like, it is polite to accept or comment on the solution(s) given. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me. Thanks for all the feedback!

```
final Charset charset = Charset.forName(charsetName);
for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
    bb.putInt(i);
    System.out.println(new String(bb.array(), charset).trim());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following to print all the valid characters in the order of the encoded values.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    printCharactersFor("US-ASCII");
    printCharactersFor("IBM037");
}

private static void printCharactersFor(String charsetName) {
    System.out.println("Character set map for " + charsetName);
    Charset charset = Charset.forName(charsetName);
    SortedMap<BigInteger, String> charsInEncodedOrder = new TreeMap<BigInteger, String>();
    for (int i = Character.MIN_VALUE; i < Character.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
        String s = Character.toString((char) i);
        byte[] encoded = s.getBytes(charset);
        String decoded = new String(encoded, charset);
        if (s.equals(decoded))
            charsInEncodedOrder.put(new BigInteger(1, encoded), i + " " + s);
    }
    for (Map.Entry<BigInteger, String> entry : charsInEncodedOrder.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey().toString(16) + " " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

and it produces something which matches http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/IBM037/grid.htm

Comment: Thanks! This gave me an idea on what I have to do.  I'm surprised there's no easy way to do this though.

Comment: @Gyles, perhaps because its not done very often.  You could create an open source library to do this if you think its generally useful ;)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the values from `0` to `127` (or `255`) and *decode* them using the wanted character set, resulting in “normal” java `char` values. Now you can check for the alphanumericality of those values using [Character.isLetterOrDigit(char)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetterOrDigit%28char%29) and use them to your liking.

Comment: This is actually a very smart way to do this too.  I'm posting my code based on this.