# Returning all the values of a charset java

Tags: java, arrays, character-encoding, char

Using the `java.nio.charset.Charset` class, is it possible to return all of the values contained within a charset and load them into some sort of array?

For example: Load all of the values of say the "UTF-8" charset into a `char[]` or `byte[]` to be used for whatever. Is this at all possible in Java?

In this case, it would be much more convienient to load all of the characters in a charset into an array of type `T` and iterate over the array rather than use an iterative `for` loop to convert the `int` to a `char` or `byte`. Also, in response to zapl's comment: would there be a method of ignoring all of the values that are unassigned?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389309/how-to-iterate-navigate-through-each-character-in-a-character-set-e-g-us-asci

Comment: Are you sure you want all of them? *"As of Unicode 8.0, released in June 2015, 264,256 (24%) of these code points are allocated, including 120,737 (11%) assigned characters, 137,468 (12%) reserved for private use, 2,048 for surrogates, and 66 designated non-characters, leaving 849,856 (76%) unassigned."*. They can certainly not be represented as `byte` (max 256 different ones), and only some as a single `char`(64k). You need `int`s to get all of them.

Comment: I have revised my question in response to your comment, and the possible solution proposed which does not directly solve my problem.